# MySQL CASE when SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN `def_spell`.`type` = 0 THEN `spells_damage`.* 
            WHEN `def_spell`.`type` = 1 THEN `spells_weaken`.*
       END 
FROM `def_spell` 
LEFT JOIN `spells_damage` ON `def_spell`.`id` = `spells_damage`.`spell_id` 
LEFT JOIN `spells_weaken` ON `def_spell`.`id` = `spells_weaken`.`spell_id` 
WHERE `def_spell`.`id` = 1;
```

Hopefully that makes sense... I'm basically trying to select everything from `spells_damage` providing `type` is 0 and everything from `spells_weaken` providing `type` is 1.

I'd also like to select everything from `def_spell` regardless.

Can someone please fix the query? I've never used cases like this before and not sure how to.

Comment: fix it? how about you format it?

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow gets rid of the ` symbols...

Comment: SELECT 
CASE WHEN `def_spell`.`type` = 0 THEN `spells_damage`.* 
WHEN `def_spell`.`type` = 1 `spells_weaken`.* END 
FROM `def_spell` 
LEFT JOIN `spells_damage` ON `def_spell`.`id` = `spells_damage`.`spell_id` 
LEFT JOIN `spells_weaken` ON `def_spell`.`id` = `spells_weaken`.`spell_id` 
WHERE `def_spell`.`id` = 1;

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow, is there a way around it doing that?

Comment: I'm not sure `SELECT CASE WHEN ... table1.* ELSE table2.*` works (it **might* if the tables have the same exact number of columns and atatypes. If it does, from a maintenance view it's terrible, and if you worked in my shop it wouldn't fly (neither does `SELECT *`). There has to be a better way, even if it means writing a longer SQL statement, to make this more readable and maintainable.

Comment: I think you need to revisit your db design.

Comment: To format code (e.g. SQL, including the back-ticks), highlight the code and use the `{}` icon above the edit box to indent it.  Note that you need at least one character in the first four columns of the code to be indented; otherwise, the editor unindents the code!  I put a '.' in column 1 and do the indent, then remove the '.' afterwards.  There might be a better way; I haven't found it yet.  Avoid tabs in the pasted code, too; they're treated as tab stops are set at 4, but they can make it messy when you're editing.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a CASE to choose between the output of the two tables like that.

Unfortunately, that's the easy bit; working out (a) what you're trying to do and (b) achieving an equivalent result is going to take a little longer.

It would be easier if you gave us information about the columns in the Spells_Weaken and Spells_Damage table.  Presumably, there are some differences; otherwise, you'd have a single table.  Indeed, a single Spells table might still be a better design.

Let's put doubts aside.  Assuming that the Spells_Weaken and Spells_Damage tables are UNION-compatible, you can use a UNION to achieve the result:

```
SELECT s.*, d.*
  FROM def_spell AS s
  LEFT JOIN spells_damage AS d ON s.id = d.spell_id
 WHERE s.type = 0
   AND s.id = 1
UNION
SELECT s.*, w.*
  FROM def_spell AS s
  LEFT JOIN spells_weaken AS w ON s.id = w.spell_id 
 WHERE s.type = 1
   AND s.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to do that.  You will need to either split it into two queries, or manually specify each of the columns with the `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.`type` = 0 THEN b.col1 
            WHEN a.`type` = 1 THEN c.col1
       END  AS col1
       , CASE WHEN a.`type` = 0 THEN b.col2
            WHEN a.`type` = 1 THEN c.col2
       END  AS col2
FROM `def_spell`  a
LEFT JOIN `spells_damage` b ON a.`id` = b.`spell_id` 
LEFT JOIN `spells_weaken` c ON a.`id` = c.`spell_id` 
WHERE a.`id` = 1;
```